# CSOM Powershell to check if feature is activated

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, site-collection, feature

Is there any CSOM PowerShell code to check if a site collection feature is activated or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There can be better and different ways to check if Feature is activated or not. But once I used below code.

Connect to your site collection using CSOM code, and load feature as below.

```
$FeatureID = "000-000000-0000" #GUID of your feature
$SiteFeatures = $context.Site.Features 
$context.Load($SiteFeatures)
$context.ExecuteQuery()

$IsFeatureExists = $SiteFeatures | Where {$_.DefinitionID -eq $FeatureID}

if ($IsFeatureExists)
{
    # Feature Exist (Activated)
}
else
{
    # Feature do not exist (Not Activated)

}
```